# select -first 1 on a large file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following command on a very large text file. However, it's very slow

```
((cat largefile.txt | select -first 1).split(",")).count()
```

Is an alternative fast way in powershell? It seems the command will scan the whole file no matter what.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To only get the first x number of lines in a text file, use the –totalcount parameter:

```
((Get-Content largefile.txt -totalcount 1).split(",")).count
```

Comment: This method loads the entire file into memory first, before taking the first line.

Answer (score 10):

It's worse than that - it will load the whole file *and* turn it into a string array.

Use the native .NET libraries to load just the first line:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("largefile.txt")
$line = $reader.ReadLine()
$reader.Close()
```

(borrowed from [How to process a file in Powershell line-by-line as a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192419/1180926))

Comment: What about the last lines or do you just have to wait for it to go all the way through?

Comment: This method only loads the first line into memory, making it many times quicker than Get-Content on larger files.

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 : Line 2 loads the whole file in memory