# Powershell Search a pattern string in two lines together

Tags: regex, powershell, match, select-string

I am trying to search two strings in any two consecutive lines and need help.

Two search strings are `"Airport"` and `"Rate"` and sample Input file is described below :

Content of Input file :

```
1. Airport
2. Rate
3. Some text
4. Some more text
5. Airport
6. Some text
```

Desired Output :

```
1. Airport
2. Rate
```

P.S. `Airport` keyword in `5.` is not in desired output since `4.` and `6.` doesn't have `Rate` keyword.

This is how I have get it so far :

```
PS> get-content "c:\Inputfile.txt" | select-string "Airport" -context 1 | s
elect-string "Rate" > c:\airportrate.txt


Thanks.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using V3:

```
$Text = Get-Content "c:\Inputfile.txt" -Raw
[regex]$regex = '(?m)(^\d+\.\sAirport.*?\n\d+\.\sRate.*?)'
$regex.Matches($Text).value
```

From get-help get-content (V3)

-Raw 
        Ignores newline characters and returns the entire contents of a file in one string. By default, the contents of a file is returned as a array of strings that is delimited by the newline character.

Raw is a dynamic parameter that the FileSystem provider adds to the Get-Content cmdlet. This parameter works only in file system drives.

This parameter is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

Comment: `-Raw`? Not sure where you're getting that from, that results in `A parameter cannot be found that matches 'Raw'.` Doesn't exist in V3.0 documentation either: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787(v=wps.620).aspx

Comment: It works for me, and has since I installed V3.  I believe it's not included in the documentation in your link because it's provider specific.

Comment: OK, removed downvote. Have you tested this though? From your documentation: "-Raw **Ignores newline characters**" which are pretty critical to your regex.

Comment: Yes, I tested it.  When it says it ignores newline characters, it means it doesn't use them as delimiters.  It simply returns the file as a single string with the newlines embedded.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, I've tested this on your input and got the correct output.

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("c:\Inputfile.txt")
$prevLine = ""
try {
    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($prevLine -ne "") 
        {
            if ($line -Match "Rate") 
            { 
                if ($prevLine -Match "Airport")
                {
                    $prevLine
                    $line
                }
            }                
        }
        $prevLine = $line
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Credit due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192419/770270

Answer (score 1):

Read the file content in chunks of two lines, cast each chunk to a string and test if it matches your criteria:

```
PS> Get-Content .\lines.txt -ReadCount 2 | Where-Object {"$_" -match 'Airport.*rate' }
1. Airport
2. Rate
```

Comment: Isn't that going to stop finding matches if there's ever an odd number of unmatched lines between the Airport + Rate pairs?

Comment: I don't think so as odd numbered lines will result in a last group of just one line in it and it will not match.

Comment: If there's multiple sets in the file, and odd numbers of lines between two sets, you'll end up with Airport as the second element of one array, and Rate as the first element of the next.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work appropriately for me. As 'mjolinor' pointed out, it won't work if "Airport" happens to be at odd line number.

Comment: I made this getting a clue from Shay post. PS > get-childitem -recurse -filter *.txt |  select-string -pattern "Airport" -context 1 | Where
    -Object {"$_" -match "rate" } > c:\Airportrate.txt