# Powershell remove line where -notmatch IF Statement

Tags: windows, powershell, line, powershell-3.0

I have the following code:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText(".\Babytest.txt")
try {
    for(;;) 
    {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    if($line eq $null) {break}
            if($line -notMatch 'BB1') { $line }


    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

The way I understand this code, is:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText(".\Babytest.txt")
```

-- Opens the test.txt file

```
for(;;) 
        {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if($line eq $null) {break}
                 if($line -notMatch 'BB1') { $line }
```

-- If the line is null= EOF break code Else go into another IF look for all lines where there is no 'BB1' in it, output $line

**What I want to do**

First of all, this code works,  although the IF - notmatch doesn't seem to be working, I still see the lines with BB1 in them in my output to the shell. What am I missing?

How can I write this out to a file? This is kind of more loopy stuff oppose to the pipe stuff, so I'm not sure if something like

```
|out-file "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Scripts\Baby Removal Project\babyoutput.txt"
```

would work...all help is greatly appreciated... I've been researching this all day, but it seems powershell has a learning curve, I'm getting the hang of it, there's just so much you can do...

**UPDATE**

Example String:

```
AR|111000111011|500001|1|DavT|2013-09-10 12:03:18|2014-04-07 10:23:09|A25415|3|2013-08-11|2013-08-13|Y|01 |APPROVED|01 |APPROVED|35 |
```

String with no BB1

```
AR|111100001BB1|500002|1||2014-04-02 15:30:12|2014-04-04 10:55:54|A32009|3|2014-03-31|2014-04-02|Y|01 |APPROVED|03 |PENDING|34 |
```

String with BB1

I want to remove the lines like BB1 line

Comment: you need to use `-eq` not `eq`, and you could use `while(1){}` instead of `for(;;)` if you'd like .. Also, It's bad to do testing on or removal of babies

Comment: @Cole9350 lol you're a fool, thanks broseidon. I probably cannot pipe that out to an out-file, do i need to handle the output inside the second IF? or after?

Comment: and I still am not matching the lines with BB1 in them!

Comment: Either you are not giving us accurate information, or something is very weird on your system. Per all of the below answers, `-notmatch 'BB1'` should work fine.  Is the encoding of the file strange?

Comment: well i only have 5 lines, 3 of which have BB1 in string, 2 should be returned, but all 5 are returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for` loop and a `StreamReader` to read a text file, although not *wrong*, is just not a right way to do things in Powershell.  Unless you have some kind of critical performance requirement (in which case you shouldn't be scripting), it's much better to use the high-level tools that Powershell affords you.

```
Get-Content .\Babytest.txt |?{ $_ -notmatch 'BB1' } | Out-File 'BabyOutput.txt'
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: I put this in a ps1 fle and ran it, it does not take out the lines where BB1 is, nor does it output to a file...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Using .NET framework types in PowerShell is more than acceptable. There are times where it's absolutely necessary. In this case, `Get-Content` is a bit more "PowerShell friendly," but I strongly encourage people to use the .NET framework to their advantage.

Comment: You don't need to put it in a script, you can just paste it into the console.  Does `Get-Content .\Babytest.txt` output all the content you expect?  If so, your regex pattern might not be doing what you expect.

Comment: yes it does print out all contents from the file, I updated with example strings, please take a look. I am not the one who will ultimately be running the script that's why putting it in a file will be useful..

Comment: @TrevorSullivan I never said anything to the contrary, glad we are on the same page.

Comment: @latkin see string examples, do i need to change pattern match?

Comment: @Trevor - Agree with using .Net when it's to your advantage, but this is not one of those times. Get-Content with -ReadCount will outperform the .Net streamreader in this application.

Comment: @mjolinor: Right, hence I said `Get-Content` is more PowerShell friendly. I think we are all on the same page.

Comment: @Cole This streams content line by line, it does not read the whole file at once. It would rather difficult to OOM.

Comment: @Latkin yes I am well aware, and although difficult it has happened to me before. But to say using .Net in powershell is not the way of doing things is just completely false http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192072/how-to-process-a-file-in-powershell-line-by-line-as-a-stream

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It uses native powershell commands, and will actually out-perform your stream reader on large files:

```
Get-Content .\Babytest.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {
  $_ -notmatch 'BB1' |
  Add-Content '\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Scripts\Baby Removal Project\babyoutput.txt'
}
```

Edit:  Using the posted test data-

```
'AR|111000111011|500001|1|DavT|2013-09-10 12:03:18|2014-04-07 10:23:09|A25415|3|2013-08-11|2013-08-13|Y|01 |APPROVED|01 |APPROVED|35 |',
'AR|111100001BB1|500002|1||2014-04-02 15:30:12|2014-04-04 10:55:54|A32009|3|2014-03-31|2014-04-02|Y|01 |APPROVED|03 |PENDING|34 |'|
set-content ./babytest.txt

Get-Content .\Babytest.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {
  $_ -notmatch 'BB1'
}

AR|111000111011|500001|1|DavT|2013-09-10 12:03:18|2014-04-07 10:23:09|A25415|3|2013-08-11|2013-08-13|Y|01 |APPROVED|01 |APPROVED|35 |
```

Comment: Strange, Idk what I could be doing wrong...Look at strings, do I need to change my Expression to match? This works just like others work, but none match the BB1 strings and remove them...thank you for your time, keep trying please!

Comment: The character string 'BB1' does not appear in your second example. We need a better explanation of what it is you're trying to filter on.

Comment: I have tried, notmatch on entire numberstring and bb1, but it always outputs the BB1 string

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing old data in the output file?  I updated the answer using your test data, and it appears to work. Are you clearing that output file between tests?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, but what do I know:

```
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if($line -notlike "*BB1*")
    {
        $line
    }
}
```

Comment: also does not take out the BB1 let me give you an example line