# Read file line by line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I want to read a file line by line in PowerShell. Specifically, I want to loop through the file, store each line in a variable in the loop, and do some processing on the line.

I know the Bash equivalent:

```
while read line do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
          # work here
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Not much documentation on PowerShell loops.

Comment: The selected answer from Mathias is not a great solution. `Get-Content` loads the entire file into memory at once, which will fail or freeze on large files.

Comment: @KolobCanyon that is completely untrue. By default Get-Content loads each line as one object in the pipeline. If you're piping to a function that doesn't specify a `process` block, and spits out another object per line into the pipeline, then that function is the problem. Any problems with loading the full content into memory are not the fault of `Get-Content`.

Comment: @TheFish `foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt)` It will load the entire file into memory before it begins iterating. If you don't believe me, go get a 1GB log file and try it.

Comment: @KolobCanyon That's not what you said. You said that Get-Content loads it all into memory which is not true. Your changed example of foreach would, yes; foreach is not pipeline aware.

`Get-Content .\file.txt | ForEach-Object -Process {}` is pipeline aware, and will not load the entire file into memory. By default Get-Content will pass one line at a time through the pipeline.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

> Not much documentation on PowerShell loops.

Documentation on loops in PowerShell is plentiful, and you might want to check out the following help topics: [`about_For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for), [`about_ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach), [`about_Do`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do), [`about_While`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while).

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        # Work here
    }
}
```

Another idiomatic PowerShell solution to your problem is to pipe the lines of the text file to the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object):

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match $regex){
        # Work here
    }
}
```

---

Instead of regex matching inside the loop, you could pipe the lines through [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object) to filter just those you're interested in:

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match $regex} | ForEach-Object {
    # Work here
}
```

Comment: the last one is the most idiomatic for powershell, and can be even more succinctly written with `gc 'file.txt' | ?{ $_ -match $regex } | %{ <#stuff#> }`

Comment: Yes but, "succinct' and 'lucid' are two different things. If you need anyone to read this script ever then I beg you - don't do this to us.

Comment: Get-Content reads the whole file into memory. For large files, this could be a bad approach.

Comment: @Jayanth Not before it starts pushing output downstream. `Get-Content ... |ForEach-Object { ... }` has very different performance characteristics than, say `(Get-Content ...) |ForEach-Object { ... }`, at least for very large files.

Comment: @Mathias, thanks for the info. Could you update your answer with this detail for the "Get-Content ... | ForEach-Object" part of the solution?

Comment: @Jayanth Please read the answer - the second example is quite literally `Get-Content .\file.txt | ForEach-Object { ... }` :)

Comment: @Mathias, But it does not mention the memory aspect. As you admit in your previous reply, the first two examples you provided deal with memory differently.

Comment: @Jayanth I absolutely did not. I said that `(Get-Content ...)` (ie. _blocking_ the `Get-Content` call) would have very different performance characteristics. The very first example is `foreach($line in Get-Content ...){ ... }`, and similarly to the second example, `foreach` will start consuming output from `Get-Content` as soon as it's available. Feel free to post your own answer if you feel that mine is incomplete

Comment: @Mathias. Try below code on a large file. For a 500 MB file on my laptop, it takes 25 seconds to reach the "$date2 = get-date" line of code. This indicates the first example in your answer reads the whole file (or atleast a large part of it) into memory before hitting the loop.

$date1 = get-date;
$x = 0;
foreach ($line in Get-Content $FileName)
    if ($x -lt 1) {
        $date2 = get-date;
    }
    $x += 1;
}
($date2 - $date1).seconds;

Comment: @Jayanth That's because you're waiting for the loop to finish before using the `$date2` value you obtained 25 seconds earlier. Try adding a `break` statement after `$date2 = get-date` and you'll find it's near instant - proving that `Get-Content` does not complete reading the file before loop iteration starts

Comment: Tried the break just after evaluating $date2. 29 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256051/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-jayanth).

Answer (score 90):

`Get-Content` has bad performance; it tries to read the file into memory all at once.

C# (.NET) file reader reads each line one by one

**Best Performace**

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\path\to\file.txt"))
{
       $line
}
```

Or slightly less performant

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\path\to\file.txt") | ForEach-Object {
       $_
}
```

The `foreach` statement will likely be slightly faster than `ForEach-Object` (see comments below for more information).

Comment: I would probably use `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\path\to\file.txt") | ForEach-Object { ... }`.  The `foreach` statement will [load the entire collection to an object](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/).  `ForEach-Object` uses a pipeline to stream with.  Now the `foreach` statement will likely be slightly faster than the `ForEach-Object` command, but that's because loading the whole thing to memory usually is faster.  `Get-Content` is still terrible, however.

Comment: @BaconBits `foreach()` is an alias of `Foreach-Object`

Comment: That is a very common misconception.  `foreach` is a statement, like `if`, `for`, or `while`.  `ForEach-Object` is a command, like `Get-ChildItem`.  There is also a default alias of `foreach` for `ForEach-Object`, but it is only used when there is a pipeline.  See the long explanation in `Get-Help about_Foreach`, or click the link in my previous comment which goes to an entire article by Microsoft's The Scripting Guys about the differences between the statement and the command.

Comment: @BaconBits https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/  Learned something new. Thanks. I assumed they were the same because `Get-Alias foreach` => `Foreach-Object`, but you are right, there are differences

Comment: @BaconBits I added your suggestion to the answer

Comment: That will work, but you'll want to change `$line` to `$_` in the loop's script block.

Comment: Kolob Canyon, I upvoted your answer because of the techniques it suggests.  However, if what @BaconBits said is true, about foreach()  loading the entire collection to an object--and your subsequent comments indicate that you agree--then it logically follows that the first snippet suffers from precisely the same problem that you are suggesting it as a remedy for.  i.e., "...has bad performance [because it reads] the file into memory all at once." Your final statement attempts to clear this up, but I suggest editing the intro to your answer to make it clear up front.

Comment: Not working on the Windows 7: `Method invocation failed because [System.IO.File] doesn't contain a method named 'ReadLines'.` [This answer works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192419/3632516).

Comment: @anilech You are probably on an old version of Powershell. If you're are on `2` or below, you should upgrade

Comment: @KolobCanyon performance was never mentioned as an issue on the OP.

Comment: @TheFish true, but this being a canonical question, I think people should know that using `Get-Content` is the devil.

Comment: @BaconBits  With Get-Content, I can join the strings like this `(Get-Content .\BTSManifest.txt | Join-String -Separator ',')`  . How to perform such a join using these two methods?

Comment: I never understood why people use Powershell specific commandlets when you can use .NET classes directly. Not only is it more readable to devs who know other languages like C#, it's more intuitive because you can see the exact class that is being used, and you can look that class up to see what other methods it has.

Answer (score 14):

**Reading Large Files Line by Line**

**Original Comment (1/2021)**
I was able to read a 4GB log file in about 50 seconds with the following. You may be able to make it faster by loading it as a C# assembly dynamically using PowerShell.

```
[System.IO.StreamReader]$sr = [System.IO.File]::Open($file, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
while (-not $sr.EndOfStream){
    $line = $sr.ReadLine()
}
$sr.Close()
```

**Addendum (3/2022)**
Processing the large file using C# embedded in PowerShell is even faster and has less "gotchas".

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ProcessLargeFile
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void ProcessLine(string line)
        {
            return;
        }

        public static void ProcessLogFile(string path) {
            var start_time = DateTime.Now;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));
            try {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream){
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    ProcessLine(line);
                }
            } finally {
                sr.Close();
            }
            var end_time = DateTime.Now;
            var run_time = end_time - start_time;
            string msg = "Completed in " + run_time.Minutes + ":" + run_time.Seconds + "." + run_time.Milliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessLogFile("c:\\users\\tasaif\\fake.log");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
"@
 
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp

PS C:\Users\tasaif> [ProcessLargeFile.Program]::ProcessLogFile("c:\\users\\tasaif\\fake.log")
Completed in 0:17.109
```

Comment: Tareq Saif -- 4 GB in 50 secs has not been true for me with this example. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ToC I tried it again today and I believe I filtered my dataset first before performing any function calls.
For example
if ($line.Contains("relevant information")){
  Do something useful
}

If you try running a function on every line (including an empty function) it takes much longer. If you must run a function for each line and want it to run faster I would look into parallelizing the code maybe using threads.

Comment: Apparently, I can't go back to modify my comment. I tried embedding C# in the PowerShell and it doesn't suffer from that limitation. With an empty function and just reading the lines, it processed in 18 seconds. I'll add the code to my comment above.

Comment: -Thank you, I'll try this and see how it plays out. Appreciate you taking time to add more details !!

Answer (score 10):

The almighty [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) works well here:

```
'one
two
three' > file

$regex = '^t'

switch -regex -file file { 
  $regex { "line is $_" } 
}
```

Output:

```
line is two
line is three
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Set-Location 'C:\files'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Name -Include *.txt
foreach($file in $files){
        Write-Host("Start Reading file: " + $file)
        foreach($line in Get-Content $file){
            Write-Host($line)
        }
        Write-Host("End Reading file: " + $file)                
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).