# Read TFS build variables from file

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to read a file from the git source control and set values to TFS build variables so that we can use them in other steps?

We have a file with the version info and the branch (VER_TYPE=3 is DEV) that we use to set up assembly version together with the build number

`VER_MAJOR=2018`
`VER_MINOR=1`
`VER_TYPE=3`

Tks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to define or modify a variable from a script, use the `task.setvariable` logging command.

> Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. **The first
>   task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the
>   variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an
>   environment variable.**
>
> When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will be saved
>   as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables are not passed
>   into tasks as environment variables and must be passed as inputs.

**Examples:**

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;issecret=true;]testvalue
```

More details please refer [Define and modify your variables in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/_shared/set-variables-in-scripts?tabs=batch)

You can run a script on windows agent using either a **Batch** script task or **PowerShell** script task. You just need to read the specific file in source control, download it in the workspace on the build agent. Then read the file, a way using powershell for your reference: [Read file line by line in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell)

Comment: I got a 404 on the "Define and modify your variables in a script" link.  I think the documentation has moved to here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch