# Convert a bash script into PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, unix

I'm apologized,
I have a (Bash) Unix shell script that should be run on PowerShell. I have to like to convert this but don't know how.

__ Bash___

```
For i in $(cat ./readersG3.txt); 
Do rigado gateway remove-tag $i --key=ble-controller-PROD; 
Done
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to read the lines of a file in `bash`. See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this thread 
[Read file line by line in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell)

```
Get-Content .\readersG3.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # do your operation on each $_
}
```

or

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\readersG3.txt) {
   # do your operation  $line
}
```