# How to get PyPi link, license, code and homepage of Python/Pip packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

When running `pip list` or `pip freeze`, is there a way to emit additional details for each package?

#### Further details:

In our project, we must report the packages we're using, their origin and their license. What I'm trying to retrieve would be similar to e.g.:

```
Package       Version PyPi Link                       License                   
------------- ------- ------------------------------- --------------------------
Flask         1.1.2   https://pypi.org/project/Flask/ BSD License (BSD-3-Clause)
Others...     1.2.3   ...                             ...
```

Entries I'm trying to find besides `PyPi Link`:

- PyPi Link
- Homepage (`https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/` in case of flask)
- Code (`https://github.com/pallets/flask` in case of flask)
- License (`BSD License (BSD-3-Clause)` in case of Flask)

Answer (score 3):

If you run `pip show <name>` ([documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/)) it would give you more details including the license, and I believe any additional link metadata within the package. If you have a requirements.txt file in your project you can do a [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)(linux/mac) or [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell)(windows) script to run the command for each dependency if doing it one at a time is too much hassle.

You can also use the`--verbose` to get even more details like classifiers etc.