# How to copy multiple files to a new folder when only filepaths are provided using powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, copy-item

I have a network drive contains couple millions of files from multiple folders. I was provided with a list filepaths in delimited format. How to copy all the files into one single folder using PowerShell?

Comment: Having a few million files in one NTFS directory is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197162/503046). Nevertheless, try `import-csv` to import the file and the a `foreach` loop with `copy-item`.

Comment: Gotta agree with Von with the exception of piping it to `Copy-item` which should accept all those names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by looping each filepath, and copy using current filepath as first parameter and some common path variable for destination

- Loop file content ([Read file line by line in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell))
- Copy item to wanted folder: [Example]`Copy-Item "C:\Wabash\Logfiles\mar1604.log.txt" -Destination "C:\Presentation"` (From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1)