# Need a way to write the remaining data of file after finding a string in Poweshell

Tags: powershell

I have a large file (250 Gb) that I need to search for a string, once I find it I need to copy everything from that line through the end of the file.
Example file:

```
Bird
Lion
Tiger
Jaguar
Frog
Snake
```

Result would be:

```
Jaguar
Frog
Snake
```

I am new to PowerShell and have tried the following but that just finds the string Jaguar and prints it, I need the following lines as well.

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Dump\test1.txt" |
Select-String 'Jaguar' |
Set-Content -Path "C:\Dump\test2.txt"
```

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match or can the word be contained or concatenated with other word?

Comment: It will be an exact match.

Answer (score 5):

Since you say your file is really large (and possibly the resulting file is also large), I think I would use a `switch` and a StreamWriter

```
$writer  = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new('C:\Dump\test2.txt')
$foundMarker = $false
switch -Regex -File 'C:\Dump\test1.txt' {
    '\bJaguar\b' { $foundMarker = $true; $writer.WriteLine($_) }
    default { if ($foundMarker) { $writer.WriteLine($_) } }
}
# clean up
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Dispose()
```

The `\b` surrounding your keyword `Jaguar` make it a 'whole word' search.

P.S. If you need the keyword to be matched Case-sensitively, add switch `CaseSensitive` to the switch: `switch -Regex -CaseSensitive -File 'C:\Dump\test1.txt' {...}`

Comment: Nicely done. Note that calling `.Dispose()` (or `.Close()`)  _implicitly_ flushes, so I don't think you need an explicit `.Flush()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple understable function that you can use with large files:

```
function Get-Content-Since-Equals-To-File(){
    param (
        [string] $Path,        
        [string] $LineText,
        [string] $PathNewFile
    )
    $writer  = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($PathNewFile)
    $continue=0
    foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($Path))
    {    
        if($line.Equals($LineText)){$continue=1}
        if( $continue -eq 1){
            #Add-Content -Path $PathNewFile -Value $line #According to  mklement0 using Add-Content is really slow
            $writer.WriteLine($line);
        }
    }
    $writer.Dispose();    
}
```

Then you can invoke that function by just  pass the file path , the word since you want to get the file and the new file Path:

```
Get-Content-Since-Equals-To-File -Path ./1.txt "Jaguar" -PathNewFile './newFile.txt'
```

The above result produce a file with the desired result(note I'm using relative paths as an example, in your day-to-day you should use absolute paths and consider the working dir aka cwd):

```
Get-Content ./newFile.txt
Jaguar
Frog
Snake
```

This function is based on [Read file line by line in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell) , because it reads line by line you can use it in large files.

In case you don't need to match you can use other conditions to adapt the function.

**Thanks to @mkelement0** for the improvement on Add-Content, I updated the code by using a StreamWriter.

Comment: Thanks for updating. You can solve the relative-path problem by replacing `[System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($PathNewFile)` with `[System.IO.StreamWriter]::new((Convert-Path -LiteralPath $PathNewFile))`. Also, it's better to use `[bool]` values to represent Boolean values: `$continue = $false` / `$continue = $true` and `if ($continue) ...`.