# Use .NET for fast read/write of large files

Tags: powershell

i am trying to search through a number of large files and replace parts of the text, but i keep running into errors.

i tried this, but sometimes i'll get an 'out of memory' error in powershell

```
#region The Setup
$file = "C:\temp\168MBfile.txt"

$hash = @{
    ham = 'bacon'
    toast = 'pancakes'
}
#endregion The Setup

$obj = [System.IO.StreamReader]$file
$contents = $obj.ReadToEnd()
$obj.Close()

foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
    $contents = $contents -replace [regex]::Escape($key), $hash[$key]
}
try {
    $obj = [System.IO.StreamWriter]$file
    $obj.Write($contents)
} finally {
    if ($obj -ne $null) {
        $obj.Close()
    }
}
```

then i tried this (in the ISE), but it crashes with a popup message (sorry, don't have the error on hand) and tries to restart the ISE

```
$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$obj = [System.IO.StreamReader]$file
while (!$obj.EndOfStream) {
    $line = $obj.ReadLine()
    foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
        $line = $line -replace [regex]::Escape($key), $hash[$key]
    }
    [void]$arraylist.Add($line)
}
$obj.Close()
$arraylist
```

and finally, i came across something like this, but i'm not sure how to use it properly, and i am not even sure if i am going about this the right way.

```
$sourcestream = [System.IO.File]::Open($file)
$newstream = [System.IO.File]::Create($file)
$sourcestream.Stream.CopyTo($newstream)
$sourcestream.Close()
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a readcount of 1000 and tweak it based on the performance you get:

```
get-content textfile -Readcount 1000 | 
    foreach-object {do something} | 
    set-content textfile
```

or

```
(get-content textfile -Readcount 1000) -replace 'something','withsomething' | 
set-content textfile
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I get any lines after I'm done with the first 1000?

Comment: from the help file : `-ReadCount<Int64>
Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the content at one time.
This parameter does not change the content displayed, but it does affect the time it takes to display the content. As the value of ReadCount increases, the time it takes to return the first line increases, but the total time for the operation decreases. This can make a perceptible difference in very large items`

Comment: Does your example work if I'm trying to write to the same file I'm reading from?

Comment: No it won't and neither will streams. To write to the source file you need to first read the whole file to memory. You can however write to a temp file and replace the source file when your done.

Comment: yup as @FrodeF. mentioned writing to the source while it is still being read is not possible. Using a temp file is a much safer option because that way your source is untouched.once you are satisfied with the results you could use `remove-item` to remove the source and perhaps rename the newfile

Comment: I'm still not getting it to work right. out of memory error. the 168mb file has no carriage returns or line feeds - it's all a single line. is there any way to only read so many characters or bytes at a time?

Comment: none that i am aware of but take a look at this thread - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192072/how-to-process-a-file-in-powershell-line-by-line-as-a-stream`.....also perhaps you could explore other programming languages that are tailored more towards text processing....